# Looking for a file in google youtube upload api

Tags: import, youtube-api

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
```

I can't find where the package for this import is. I got the code I'm using here:  https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/java/youtube-cmdline-uploadvideo-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/youtube_cmdline_uploadvideo_sample/UploadVideo.java

Please help

Answer (score 0):

It's in guava-jdk5-13.0.jar

It's a sub dependency of both of

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-services-youtube</artifactId>
  <version>${project.youtube.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
  <version>${project.http.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

If you check out the full project with git and let Maven to get the dependencies, that would be easier for you.

Comment: I set it up, letting maven do the dependencies, and am now reaching this error which I can't figure out:GoogleJsonResponseException code: 403 : Access Not Configured
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Access Not Configured",
    "reason" : "accessNotConfigured"
  } ],
  "message" : "Access Not Configured"
}

Comment: You need first set your access from dev console (https://code.google.com/apis/console/b)   Though you are Missing ESSENTIAL information, I Strongly suggest you to first read the getting started guide(https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) and rest of the documentation (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3)